# Invoking SSIS Package from WCF service (tcp binding)

Tags: .net, wcf, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to invoke an SSIS package in SQL Server 2012 (local installation) via a WCF service hosted in local IIS. The WCF Service is using tcp binding and the IIS app pool is running under NETWORKSERVICE. I'm using a console application to test the WCF service. After the console application calls the WCF service, the WCF service attempts to invoke a SSIS package on the local SQL Server and throws a "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\MYMACHINENAME$'."

The WCF service uses integrated security in the SQL Server connection string because Integration services cannot be invoked using sql accounts. I've created SQL logins for NETWORKSERVICE and MYDOMAIN\MYMACHINENAME$ and granted them dbo permissions to the databases and dbo + ssis_admin to the SSIS Catalog database SSISDB. As per MSDN, creating the SQL logins should work but it is not working (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx#paght000015_sqlserver).

Is there anything else that needs to be done in SQL Server to allow the account access? 
In dev and production the plan is to create a domain service account and run the app pool under the service account. Are there any alternatives to this approach?

My environment information is below. Thank you in advance for your help.

Windows 7 Enterprise 
SQL Server 2012 
SSIS 2012 
.NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I've created SQL logins for NETWORKSERVICE and MYDOMAIN\MYMACHINENAME$" do you actually mean you created SQL Server authenticated logins or did you create logins based on these Windows accounts?

If you are accessing the SQL server across the network, then you need to create a login using Windows authentication for domain\servername$, not a SQL login.