# Calling SSIS package from WCF

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, ssis

There was a similar question asked here, but no real answer.

Here's the previous question:
[Invoking SSIS Package from WCF service (tcp binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951611/invoking-ssis-package-from-wcf-service-tcp-binding)

I have a very similar problem. I've got a VB.net application for the UI, and it calls a C# WCF service that I'm hosting locally in IIS, which in turn calls an SSIS package that I've deployed to SQL Server 2012 using the Project Deployment method. If I use the WCF Test Client to test the WCF call to the SSIS package, it runs fine. Once I deploy the WCF service to IIS, then try to run my VB.net app in Visual Studio 2013 and step through the code calling the WCF service, then step into the WCF service code, once it gets to the line of code that attempts to connect to my SQL Server instance, I get an exception stating

> Failed to connect to server

The `InnerException` is

> Login failed for user 'DomainName\PCName$

The connection string in the WCF code is like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PCName\SQLServerInstance;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

I've tried adding a Windows Authentication login to SQL Server for `DomainName\PCName$`, but it made no difference. Why would the WCF service be able to successfully connect to my SQL Server instance when I test it in Visual Studio using the WCF Test Client, but not be able to successfully connect once I publish the WCF service to my local IIS?

Please help me, I've tried EVERYTHING (I think). . .

Comment: To confirm that the DomainName\PCName$ account does/doesn't have access to your database, can you try running Visual Studio as DomainName\PCName$? I would expect that in this case, your WCF service won't be able to connect to DBName.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast!!! When I go to run Visual Studio as a different user, it prompts for a username and a password.  I tried using a blank password, but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: In fact, even if I change the connect string to include my credentials (the SQL Server instance is hosted on my PC, on which I am an admin), I get "Login failed for user 'MyUserName'.  I just can't understand why the WCF service can connect fine from VS, but not from IIS once I publish it. . .

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix!  Thanks for the suggestion Dean - this was a doozy.  I'm new to posting to Stack Overflow, so please excuse my poor formatting.  Basically, the answer was found here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff441dc3-b43b-486b-8be1-00126cf53812/calling-ssis-packages-from-aspnet-packages-with-file-system-tasks-end-abruptly?forum=sqlintegrationservices

I created a new application pool in IIS, just for WCF services.  I changed the Identity of that pool to a user that was an admin and had dbo privileges on the SQL Server DB.  I then moved my WCF service to that new application pool, restarted IIS, and everything worked!